# Not able to ssh as root on 14.04.2

Tags: ssh, password, root, authentication

I have done all the workarounds, yet, I am still not able to ssh as root.
I have already modified `PermitRootLogin` to yes, and I have reset `ssh` services. I have even rebooted the VM, but it is just not working.

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
```

Comment: The reason I need ssh as root is to be able to install contrail. The contrail installation is trying to use the root login.

Comment: Do you have a root account? Ubuntu does not have one by default. Also, you can get root-like `shell` access using `sudo -i`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, there is a root account. I can use wrrot from console using sudo su:  root@contrail:/home/agabsi

Comment: You don't have a *real* root account. If you did, then just `su` or `su root` should result in a root prompt. If you have to use `sudo su`, you don't have a proper root account. You only get a *proper* root account if you manually set it with `sudo passwd root`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 'root' account available for login by default.  It is locked in a default installation.  You don't state where your install runs from, so I am going to assume it's running from your remote user account on the server.

You *can* enable the `root` account if you wish, but there's more 'secure' approaches to do this, than just enabling the account.  I've detailed some approaches to gaining `root` privileges to run an installation file on a system.

---

### The safe way: Use `sudo` to temporarily gain root privileges for the application to run as once.

Assuming this is a file you have to execute, you can run your installer as `root` by running this command, replacing `/path/to/installer` with the real path:

```
sudo /path/to/installer
```

---

### The not-as-safe way: Use `sudo` to drop into a `root` shell prompt, and execute installation commands.

Run this command top drop yourself into a `root` login, and then you can run commands as superuser:

```
sudo su -
```

Once here, execute the command as you would without `sudo`:

```
/path/to/installer
```

*Note that this is a very dangerous thing - you can literally break your system with this approach if you don't know what you're doing on the command line.*

Once done, `exit` the shell and drop back to your unprivileged user.

---

### The extremely dangerous insecure way: Enable `root` account by setting a password

> ### WARNING!
>
> Before attempting ***ANY*** of these commands, be aware that by enabling the root account, and permitting Root Login with "Yes" and not "without-password" through ssh, if even for just a moment, you are opening your system to brute-force login attempts and other security risks.  If you do this, then AS SOON AS IS LOGICAL you should re-disable the `root` account.
>
> Either set `PermitRootLogin without-password` and configure SSH Key Authentication, or understand that as soon as you are done, you should lock the root account again, and set `PermitRootLogin` to `no` or `without-password`.

The least secure approach is to enable the root account by setting a password.  You can do this by using this command on your user who has `sudo` privileges (you don't have to specify 'root' here though):

```
sudo passwd
```

Set a root password (the password will not display, nor will any asterisks, but it is accepting the password), then the `root` account will be activated.  You will then be able to login to the account, based on your existing SSH settings you stated.

***As soon as you no longer need the `root` user***, please run this to re-disable and re-lock the `root` user from your `sudo`-enabled account:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

You should also set `PermitRootLogin` to `no` or `without-password` in your `sshd_config` as well when you do this.

Comment: Thank you very much, sudo passwd is what I needed. I am able to access the server now as root...Thank you again very much :-)

Comment: @agabsi As soon as you are done, lock the user again - DO NOT do everything as root!